# Sorting vectors in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector

I need to sort the data structure  `vector<pair<unsigned, pair<vector<unsigned>, vector<unsigned> > > > sbp` first by sbp.second.second vector and for equal values of sbp.second.second by sbp.second.first -- both the vectors are compared by (i) size of vectors; (ii) if size of vectors are equal, then vectors are lexicographically sorted. For doing so, I wrote the following code. But I dont know why but this code is getting stuck in an infinite loop. Can someone please help me with as to where am I going wrong.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
typedef std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned> > vec_pair;

bool sortingFunc(const pair<unsigned,vec_pair>& a, const pair<unsigned,vec_pair>& b)
{
    if((a.second).second.size() == (b.second).second.size()) {
        if(std::lexicographical_compare((a.second).second.begin(), (a.second).second.end(), (b.second).second.begin(), (b.second).second.end()))//a<b
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            if((a.second).first.size() == (b.second).first.size()) {
                return std::lexicographical_compare((a.second).first.begin(), (a.second).first.end(), (b.second).first.begin(), (b.second).first.end());
            } else {
                // Sort by size.
                return (a.second).first.size() < (b.second).first.size();
            }            
        }
    } else {
        // Sort by size.
        return (a.second).second.size() < (b.second).second.size();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<pair<unsigned, pair<vector<unsigned>, vector<unsigned> > > > sbp;
    std::sort(sbp.begin(), sbp.end(), sortingFunc);
}
```

I am using C++11 (gcc 4.8.2)

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger to see what is going on?

Comment: And then, where was the code getting stuck? Was it in the lexicographical_compare, the sorting function, or somewhere else?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The code got stuck in the sorting function

Comment: Check which elements are compared in the infinite loop. I think the standard library is trying to be helpful by doing something like `a < b` -> `true`, `b < a` -> `true` (which should be impossible) in an infinite loop. It gives you a chance to see the 2 offending elements with a debugger and fix your comparison function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `std::tie` or `make_tuple` with rvalue:

```
bool sortingFunc(const pair<unsigned, vec_pair>& a, const pair<unsigned, vec_pair>& b)
{
    return std::make_tuple(a.second.second.size(), std::ref(a.second.second), a.second.first.size(), std::ref(a.second.first))
         < std::make_tuple(b.second.second.size(), std::ref(b.second.second), b.second.first.size(), std::ref(b.second.first));
}
```

Your case is not correct with

```
if(std::lexicographical_compare((a.second).second.begin(), (a.second).second.end(), (b.second).second.begin(), (b.second).second.end()))//a<b
{
    return true;
}
```

where it misses `b < a` condition.

```
else if(std::lexicographical_compare((b.second).second.begin(), (b.second).second.end(), (a.second).second.begin(), (a.second).second.end()))//b < a
{
    return true;
}
```

before the == condition.

Comment: In C++14, you can go a step further and add `auto tie_order(const pair<unsigned, vec_pair>&){return std::tie(a.second.second.size(), a.second.second, a.second.first.size(), a.second.first);}`, then `sortingFunc` becomes `return tie_order(a) < tie_order(b);`.

Comment: Does this handle the lexicographical sort condition?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Yes, that's what `operator<` for vectors does, a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: operator < for vector *uses* lexicographical order, that's why we have to add size before to handle OP's requirement.

Comment: NP, not my area of expertise for sure, just wanted to double check as the answer looked too pretty :)

Comment: @Jarod42 tie's seem pretty cool. Can you please point me to some resource from which I can learn about it more. I tried to google and read from c++reference, etc. But I am not getting an in-depth understanding from them

Comment: @Jarod42 Also I dont know why but I am getting the following  error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘long unsigned int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<unsigned int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’. Since I dont understand ties can u please help me with this a bit

Comment: @JannatArora because `std::tie` wants l-value references. Do something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7ea382205eb856e (uncleaned code ahead). A function call that returns by value is an rvalue expression.

Comment: @MarcoA. Ok thanks a lot :) Do u know of any source from which I can learn about tries

Comment: By 'tries' you mean the [data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)? I suppose you meant `std::tie`. I don't know of any source better than [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), take a look at it and arm yourself with some patience.

Comment: @JannatArora: true that std::tie cannot be used with r-value, so I fixed with `make_tuple` (and `std::ref` to avoid to copy vector).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that for this condition:

```
if(std::lexicographical_compare((a.second).second.begin(), (a.second).second.end(), (b.second).second.begin(), (b.second).second.end()))//a<b
```

You do not correctly handle the opposite condition. That is, the above line only tests `if (a.second.second < b.second.second)`. If it's true, you return true from the function, which is correct. But if it's false, you then go on to check the lower priority conditions, ignoring the possible case that `b.second.second` could be less than `a.second.second`.

Also, a slight modification of Jarod42's `std::tie` method:

```
bool sortingFunc(const pair<unsigned, vec_pair>& a, const pair<unsigned, vec_pair>& b)
{
    auto  a1 = a.second.second.size();
    auto& a2 = a.second.second;
    auto  a3 = a.second.first.size();
    auto& a4 = a.second.first;

    auto  b1 = b.second.second.size();
    auto& b2 = b.second.second;
    auto  b3 = b.second.first.size();
    auto& b4 = b.second.first;

    return std::tie(a1, a2, a3, a4) < std::tie(b1, b2, b3, b4);
}
```

What `std::tie` does is make a `std::tuple` of references to its arguments. And `operator<` is overloaded for `std::tuple` to do a lexicographical comparison on its elements from the first to the last.